# Qt: Unable to read symbols for framework

Tags: qt, linker

I am encountering this error message on the application output pane when starting to debug from within Qt Creator. After a short pause, the app fails to launch

```
Unable to read symbols for QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml (file not found).
Unable to read symbols from "QtXml" (not yet mapped into memory).
```

In my .pro, I have

```
QT += xml
```

Qt Creator > Projects > Build Environment has `PATH` set to

```
/usr/bin:/Users/me/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and `/Users/me/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/4` has the dynamic library. Where am I going wrong?

I am on OS X Lion using Qt Creator, SDK 4.7.4

Comment: To debug mode you have to have QtXmld4.dll

Comment: I am on OS X - so I don't need `.dll`

Comment: Other people seem to have the same problem - see [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22378-Qt-Creator-debugging-trouble-on-Mac-OS) and [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37167-quot-Unable-to-read-symbols-quot-Problem). It's always on Mac OS, so it might be something specific to it.